# Regarding nothingness and motion in the ocean of Matter Energy

Tags: general-relativity

I am but a humble college dropout with a keen interest in physics, but one way or another I feel I have discovered some key information that will lead to a solid theory of everything that should satisfy all parties it concerns, that is, if I can correctly format and word it. My hope here is simply some respectfully conversation regarding my outlook on things.

I have come to see energy and matter in a different way, in order to do. For any physical thing to move in any way there must be some kind of room to move within it, yes? In the fabric of space? This was one of the first thoughts I had regarding my physics research. How can things move without some kind of nothingness within or around them to allow them to move? Without some space within a particle, how could it even shape and form? It would be infinitely dense wouldn't it, it would have no energy and will have reached absolute zero and collapsed into a singularity. What is Nothing anyway? Nothing is infinite isn't it, if you think about it?

It helps me to build on this understanding picturing nothing (energy) as white, and matter (physical things) as black. Yet if you were to quantify it it would be 0, surely? Yet nothingness itself is infinite. Every physical thing must exist upon nothingness. It is the canvas for which all things lay – the very flow of time on which we exist.

Now I started to wonder how spacetime could bend, shape, and form, if it is truly the nothingness, background, that Einstein describes it as. Nothing cannot have shape? Also, seeing as bubbles and waves of matter and energy emerge from it, and from the singularity, in a big bang outlook, is it not feasible that spacetime is dark matter, dark energy respectively?

Lets talk about a singularity for a moment. When a star collapses due to every action having an equal and opposite reaction etc. The, its core collapses into a point of infinite density. It is pure matter (space) at that point, it has lost all its energy. The phenomena of dark energy is present as the singularity rips space and leaves a gap where the time, the energy,  that flows though all is revealed and we are forever expanding into it, (visualize it) at an accelerated rate.

Dark matter is a phenomenon of space as it has properties where without relativity, which is only perception, space can be deeper at certain areas, or 'thinner' (for lack of a better word). Which would allow us to use time dilation for things if we could understand this relativity of space. Also it doesn't interact with the electromagnetic field – if it were space – that would explain why.

Look at the bells spaceship paradox for instance – two ships tied to each other with a string, identical, accelerating at the same rate. Eventually the string snaps. This is because of the property of space, in that there has literally been an increase in space between them. Because spacetime is matter and energy, is it not obvious?

Now if I may quickly talk about the 4 forces that we know of. I have been thinking about all the subatomic particles and their functions, it seems they would all share some similar traits, and this whole spin number etc. thing actually confused me. Here's how I see it: They spin to the left or vice versa, or in some cases, do not spin. This depends on the mass, motion and fields present. I think we can extrapolate a lot of info on why they interact that way on a small scale from simply looking at the field around a black hole.

Also this upstream contamination issue in physics, what's that about? Seems obvious how they could roll on up there.

Anyway I have a lot more to talk about but am a little distracted from other work at the moment, I can expand on/talk about this all day but I shall await responses before adding more. Seems we are on a wild goose chase for answers that may be simpler than we realize, the more you see the less you know, as they say.

Well I'll leave this here for now, see how the responses go though and add from there. Apologies for sloppy format and unclear explanations, there is a lot on my mind for now, I'm just looking for someone to try an envision these thought experiments that I have done in order to better explain my revelations to people –  so, I'll leave it the for now and see where this goes.

I also recently wrote a second iteration of an outlook I hold that may allow to relations to an effect of a real TOE, on Reddit, however in my bad mood due to typical sheeple like (excuse the term please) responses, I also added another  to sarcastically declaration that I am the crazy one.

Anyway, I'm just looking for potential conversation, video, or meet via video link etc. to talk to a physicist that may understand, it is of great importance.

Comment: Hello! Please note that questions about personal or unpublished theories are considered off-topic on this site. See [Is non-mainstream physics appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4538/) for more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know all the reasons why people think they are right, you'll never be able to convince them that they are wrong.

So I suggest first learning more about how most physicists see the Universe, if you want any hope of convincing them otherwise.

Theories of everything do attempt to connect empty space to matter and energy.

Many physicists do think dark energy is a property of empty space. But dark matter has to satisfy many properties (cosmological evolution, formation of structure, gravitational lensing of clusters, rotation curves) so theories for dark matter are very constrained.

The more you value your ideas, the more you ought to dress them up nicely. This means organizing your thoughts to make them as easy to understand as possible. Do your best to spend time formatting and making everything clear, you owe it to yourself.